# Redirect before login in laravel to avoid second login

Tags: laravel, authentication, redirect

I have php/laravel web application. 
I use laravel auth to log in users. But when I have two open cards with login page they don't know that on one page user is logged in.

I read that I must redirect in middleware when user is logged on one page.

I try to do this in LoginController with override function, but it dosen't works.

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if (Auth::check()){
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        } else if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }
    }
```

I just want to check before log into application that is user logged, but I don't know clearly where.

Comment: Laravel automatically does that for you, you cant multi login

Comment: But why i get 419 error if I want log in on second page?

Comment: Well laravel checks whether you are logged in, if so it throws 419 exception

Comment: That's why I want to implement the redirection before checking the login to avoid this error, but I don't know where. Or maybe I want do this with wrong method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I try to explain what is happening

When you open two login forms and ofc in your login forms you already have csrf token field with generated value and ofc it's a pattern BUT

let's assume your csrf_token value is `123` in both forms and when you login successfully laravel updates your session by adding your user_id to it so if your user_id is `1` then your token would change to `1231` (again it's a hashed value but come along with me) and when you submit your second form which has `123` token, as you can guess `123` is not equal to `1231` and it throws a `TokenMissmatchException`

In your case what you can do is to open `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` and add this to your handler method

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Throwable  $exception
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 *
 * @throws \Throwable
 */
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    // Checks if exception is instance of TokenMissmatchException && it throwed in the login page
    if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException && $request->path() === 'login') {
        $redirectPath = '/';

        return redirect($redirectPath);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: Oh ok, now I understand it. But what with safety?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If someone wants to pretend to be a user using another csrf, laravel still doesn't allow unwanted access?

Comment: Yes it doesn't allow since every user token is a unique hash

Comment: I have some problem after this method. I can log in without error but when I try login with correct password I must try few times. I enter correct login and password but application redirect me to login page again few times. Is this connect to this method?

Comment: not at all, this method only checks if 419 error has been thrown and if yes it will redirect the user to the home page

Comment: oh okey, have you any ide what I should check or what could be source of problem?